# How do I get the position of the cell whose values I've just printed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

SO I'm using pandas and need to get the position of each element in the dataframe o.

I've tried iloc and index() but I haven't been able to get it to work. I'm a newbie to this.

```
o=data['Opposition'].tail(10).dropna()
o.astype('str')

for i in o:
       print("Opposition cell number:",o.index())
```

The data goes something like this:

S.no Runs Opposition

1     23   West Indies

2     54   England

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
out = data.index.get_indexer(o.index)
```

Comment: I'll give it a go!

Comment: @AarshVishen - If not working, try create some sample data with expected output.

Comment: So I tried  :   o.get_indexer(i.index) but I got an error saying Series object has no attribute called 'get_indexer'

Comment: @AarshVishen - ok, can you add some sample data and excepted output?

Comment: Hi just added an image of the excel sheet. I'd like position of an Opposition cell

Comment: @AarshVishen - [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Oh I'll remove it shortly. Any ideas on getting the position though?

Comment: @AarshVishen - hmm, I have problem not uderstand what you need, so ask for sample data with expected output.

Comment: Ok suppose I store Oppostion column as such: o=data['Opposition'].tail(10) and i am iterating using the for loop as shown above. And I'd like the position of each element in o as I print it so: print("Oppostion:",o); print ("Opposition index/position",<index_opposition>)